CPR SetInterface Changes to Networkstack
I'm trying to understand the details of the 'SetInterface' command of the cpp CPR library.
In the greater scope I am trying to deploy an envoy service mesh on top of the OAI 5G network implementation. Therefore I deployed the envoy container together with the services of the 5G network in a pod. Inside of it I used iptables rules to route the traffic from the service container to the envoy proxy.
So I have the following architecture:
api1 <--> envoy1 <--> envoy2 <--> api2
If I run a python server on the one side and a client on the other side everything works. But when I exchange the client with the following client.cpp application the request fails. This is the logic which the OAI implementation uses for their connection establishment and it uses the CPR library which then uses libcurl under the hood.
This is my client.cpp:
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Specify the interface to bind to
    std::string interface = "eth0";

    // Create a cpr session
    cpr::Session session;

    // Set the interface
    session.SetInterface(cpr::Interface{interface});

    // Set the URL to the server
    session.SetUrl(cpr::Url{"http://10.1.15.49:8080/"});
    
    // Set HTTP version to HTTP/2
    session.SetHttpVersion(cpr::HttpVersion{cpr::HttpVersionCode::VERSION_2_0});

    // Send GET request
    cpr::Response response = session.Get();

    // Output the response
    std::cout << "Status code: " << response.status_code << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response body: " << response.text << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

When I comment the 'session.SetInterface(...);' line it works. Therefore I am trying to understand how this line affects the network stack of the os. Can anybody help me with that?
I would be grateful for some information about the SetInterface command and the changes it does to a network call.
I have also tried to analyze the network stack the following way:

I watched with tcpdump -I any port 8080 and 15001 and there I can see the rerouted packets even with the SetInterface command.

When using 'watch iptables -t nat -n -v' the rerouted packet numbers increase by one

but the envoy1 which should process the request does not receive anything or shows any sign in the log.


These are my iptables commands i used:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 15001 -j 
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 15001

Thanks for any help!
Edit:
I have created some monitoring rules the chains of iptables like:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 15001 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 15001 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 15001 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 15001 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 15001 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j RETURN

watch iptables -t mangle -L -n -v

There I could see the difference between a connection with a 'SetInterface' and without. The packets of the connection with a selected interface where send trough:
OUTPUT -> POSTROUTING -> exit of the device
and the packets without the 'SetInterface' where send through:
OUTPUT -> POSTROUTING -> PREROUTING -> INPUT -> OUTPUT -> POSTROUTING -> exit of the device
It seems like 'SetInterface' sets the ip addresses of the packets and therefore iptables cannot change them anymore.
After I change the IPTABLES rule to:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination <ip-of-used-interface-not-localhost>:15001

the packets were send to envoy and routed correctly. Now the question is how does SetInterface prevents iptables to modify the destionation ip of the packets?

CPR's SetInterface seems to correspond to cURL's CURLOPT_INTERFACE.
It's really only useful if your machine has multiple network interfaces. When/if it does, SetInterface will choose which interface to use for the connection.
For example, let's assume you had a laptop with both Ethernet and WiFi (and both are active/available). SetInterface will let you specify whether to use Ethernet or WiFi for this particular connection. If you don't specify which to use, the OS will choose one automatically.
You wouldn't normally expect this to change the packets that get sent over the connection, only which interface those packets get routed through.

Thanks, yes it does correspond tooth 'CURLOPT_INTERFACE' The question ist how does setting this interface manually change the kernel operations for that connection so that with iptables forwarded packets are not recognized by envoy or become dropped on the way there. Do you know which steps the kernel does if I don't specify an interface? I in which order does it route and filter the packets.
